# In VScode editor shows wrong Intellisense for Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I use Javascript but Intellisense gave me a lot of Typescript interface options.
How can I stop Intellisense for Typescript interface when I'm working in Javascript?

For reference see this [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC8Tv.png).

Comment: They don't look like TypeScript interfaces - at least [`WebGLUniformLocation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLUniformLocation) is a standard JavaScript interface

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I have a lot to learn

Answer (score 0):

Those examples are standard DOM objects. To disable these, create a `jsconfig.json` at the root of you workspace that only include the standard es6 type definitions:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es6"]
    }
}
```

However, there also was a bug in VSCode <=1.13 that caused interface suggestions to show in js files: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15750

This should be fixed in VSCode 1.14+. Please let us know if you still see this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new